# How organize and test this code?

Tags: testing, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I have a conceptual doubt about how to organize and test code like the following, where a call to an auxiliary method is the first instruction of all the public methods of the class. My idea is make the code clean and testable.

The code is an example to try to illustrate this by a class "cache". This class has an optional prefix will be applied to all keys in the cache if it is set.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Cache {
    private HashMap<String, Integer> inMemoryCache;
    private String prefix;


    public Cache() {
        this.inMemoryCache = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        prefix = null;
    }

    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public int getValue(String key) throws NullPointerException {
        String prefixedKey = applyPrefixOrDefault(key);
        return inMemoryCache.get(prefixedKey);
    }

    public void setValue(String key, int value) {
        String prefixedKey = applyPrefixOrDefault(key);
        inMemoryCache.put(prefixedKey, value);
    }

    public boolean isCached(String key) {
        String prefixedKey = applyPrefixOrDefault(key);
        return inMemoryCache.containsKey(prefixedKey);
    }

    private String applyPrefixOrDefault(String key) {
        if (prefix == null) {
            return key;
        } else {
            return prefix + key;
        }
    }


    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        Cache cache = new Cache();
        cache.setPrefix("global:");
        cache.setValue("id", 4);
        int value = cache.getValue("id");
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

This code poses two questions to me:

1. If I had many methods accessing the inner hash table, would it be right separate the behavior of the cache in one class and the behavior of the prefix in other?
2. What would be the cleanest way to test this? Test the getValue, setValue and isCached is simple if we do not consider the prefix. With the prefix we need to test two things, the correct internal behavior of the cache and we need test also that all methods call applyPrefixOrDefault before accessing the data.

This is a common use case and I'm sure there must be some design pattern to organize this. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my opinion, what we miss here is a constructor that let us set the state of the cache. So I would add one as follows:

```
public Cache() {
    this(null, new HashMap<String, Integer>());
}

public Cache(String prefix, Map<String, Integer> cache) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
    this.inMemoryCache = cache;
}
```

With this new constructor, you should be able to write test-cases for every possible cache state. I would also change the visibility of the `applyPrefixOrDefault` method to protected or package so that test code can access it. For instance, to test the GetValue method, I would write:

```
public class EmptyCacheTests {

    private final Map<String, Integer> memory;
    private final String prefix;
    private final Cache cache;

    public EmptyCacheTests() {
         this.memory = new HasMap<String, Integer>();
         this.prefix = "foo";
         this.cache = new Cache(prefix, memory);
    }

    public void testGetValue() {
         String key = this.cache.applyPrefixOrDefault("bar")
         this.memory.put(key, 50);
         result = this.cache.getValue("bar");
         assertEquals(50, result, "The value retrieved is wrong!");
    }
}
```

The point here, it to allow the test to set up the internal state of the cache, so that we can then test against many different ones.

Comment: And if I had many methods (10-20 methods for example), would you consider separating the behavior of the prefix in a separate class or would you duplicate all the test cases (with prefix and without prefix)?

Comment: Yes, if you want to test with and without prefix, separating the prefix calculation in a separate class may let you build test by composition as opposed to enumerating all possible test cases.

Comment: Thinking about it, the `prefix` attribute is not related to the cache, but to the calculation/transformation of the key. I would thus create a KeyBuilder object, that would encapsulate this prefix, and would expose a `transformKey` method similar to the `applyPrefixOrDefault`. It is then possible to inject a KeyBuilder object in the constructor of the cache, so that the test can define it.